# How to use a OR condition in Android studio logcat?

Tags: android, android-studio, logcat

Lets say I want to see the logs from Tag named `DEBUG_TAG` and messages with the string `DEBUG_STRING`.

I tried: `message:DEBUG_TAG OR tag:DEBUG_STRING` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `|` symbol, e.g.:

```
message:DEBUG_STRING | tag:DEBUG_TAG
```